# MySQL query on money format

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

I got a table prices which has values similar to the following:

```
price
----------- 
21,781.00
27,615.00
46,565.00
46,565.00
48,565.00
571.00
830.00
0.00
```

By doing a query:

```
SELECT * FROM tprice ORDER BY price=0, convert(price, decimal) ASC
```

I get the following result:

```
21,781.00
27,615.00
46,565.00
46,565.00
48,565.00
571.00
830.00
```

and, doing this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tprice ORDER BY price=0, convert(price, decimal) DESC
```

I get

```
830.00
571.00
48,565.00
46,565.00
46,565.00
27,615.00
21,781.00
0.00
```

Why is the 830.00 and 571.00 not been ordered properly?

#### EDIT:

I've changed the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM tprice ORDER BY price=0, replace(',','',price), price ASC
```

It seems to be working "a bit better". The result:

```
830.00
571.00
48,565.00
46,565.00
46,565.00
27,615.00
21,781.00
0.00
```

Still trying other variations...

Comment: Store number as number, not as string. Strings are compare char by char, `'8' > '4'`, `'830' > '48,565'`.

Comment: that would be the best thing to do. problem is, that's not my design...but need to come up with a solution. but, thanks!

Comment: Solution is to change table columns definition, their type.

Comment: @panther: can't do that. I've tried and screwed up the values stored...

Comment: No solution found: I found it's easier to re-order the result based on the query filter than trying to do some fancy query to fix that. Not clean but, works...

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the uncalled lesson...

Comment: It wasn't only for you. It was for all future readers of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT price, CONVERT(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ",", ""), ".", ""),UNSIGNED INTEGER) formattedPrice
FROM testtest
ORDER BY formattedPrice;
```

This should work.

Explanation:
You saved your numbers as a string in your database. Removing everything except the numbers and converting it to an unsigned int solves your problem.

Comment: This will work fine as long as every single value has a decimal point followed by two numbers. But there's no constraint guaranteeing that.

Comment: Thanks, I did just that a couple of min. ago and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Your prices appear to be text strings (probably stored in `VARCHAR(nn)` columns) containing US-style commas for thousands separators and dots for decimal separators.

But they are currency values. You want to handle them as if they were `DECIMAL(15,2)` or some such data format.

If you do

```
 ORDER BY CONVERT(REPLACE(price,',',''), DECIMAL(15,2))
```

at the end of your SQL statement you'll get the sorting order you need. This strips the commas, then converts the remaining string to decimal.

Notice that you should do this conversion also before you try to do arithmetic with these values.  For example, you should do

```
SELECT CONVERT(REPLACE(price,',',''), DECIMAL(15,2)) AS price,
       CONVERT(REPLACE(price,',',''), DECIMAL(15,2)) * units AS total_price
```

If you're multiplying the prices by units.

The comments that suggest changing the database structure are correct, but you can work around your defective database design using these conversions.

Here's a stored function to encapsulate the conversion.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS STRING2DECIMAL$$
CREATE FUNCTION STRING2DECIMAL(input VARCHAR(255)
     ) RETURNS DECIMAL(15,2)
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(REPLACE(input,',',''), DECIMAL(15,2));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

If you define this, then you can write your queries like

```
SELECT STRING2DECIMAL(price) AS price,
       STRING2DECIMAL(price) * units AS total_price
  FROM stock
 ORDER BY total_price DESC
```

It's easier to read. That means it's easier to do your work correctly.

Finally, if you want to put back the thousands separators for display, use the FORMAT function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(STRING2DECIMAL(price) * units, 2) AS total
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to post, awesome info! I appreciate it and hope it may help others.